# Uncontrollable Mouse Pointer

Tags: mouse, touchpad, sd-card, touchscreen

Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14 series dual boot on a Panasonic CF-30.

I'm an absolute novice with Linux but I need to format micro SD cards to EXT3 format for cameras, and I have several XP machines that work fine but are essentially useless due to end of life by Microsoft. A friend suggested I install Ubuntu and after some difficulty I managed to get it installed on my Panasonic CF-30 without too many issues. I started having troubles with the mouse being pulled as though by an elastic band to the bottom left corner of the screen where it would sit and quiver in both Windows and Ubuntu. I can move it with both touch screen and touch pad, but it rarely moves where I want it to and it will snap back to the bottom left corner very quickly. A system restore fixed the problem in Windows, now it only manifests in Ubuntu. While I can find questions for other mouse issues on this forum and others, nothing seems to match the problem I'm having. When I find a solve that appears close to what I'm dealing with the proscribed fixes are explained as though they were being explained to someone who's less than a novice than I am; the terminal commands I try to execute to implement the fixes that have worked for others are rejected- "no such directory" and similar.

Seriously stuck here and vexed beyond words that I can't even manage to format a doggone micro SD card because I'm dealing with the whole "there's a hole in the bucket" song dealing with Linux. If you're kind enough to help, please assume you're helping your parent with this... via telephone... after their bed time... and explain it like I have no idea what I'm doing.

Thank you!